# Solutions of the equation $k_0\sin^{-1}(\alpha x)+k_1\sqrt{(R^2-x^2)}=\Sigma$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I need to solve the equation:
$$k_0\sin^{-1}(\alpha x)+k_1\sqrt{(R^2-x^2)}=\Sigma$$ for the variable $x$. 
$(k_0,\alpha,k_1,R,\Sigma)$ are constants. I am not able to find close solutions for it. Is there some way to solve this equation avoiding numerical methods?
Thanks.

Comment: Equations which contain trigonometric functions and "polynomials" do not show analytical solutions. This is already the case for $x=\cos(x)$. I think that you need to consider numerical methods (such as Newton).

Comment: I would say that it is impossible to obtain  'closed solutions' in the sense you mean. This is a genuine trascendental equation.